# Excel-VBA sheet split and save ends up with many blank columns delimited by commas

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to excel-vba and been able to successfully copy certain columns into new sheets and save the new sheets as separate csv files however, when I open the newly created files in notepad, i can see a ton of extra commas representing a lot of extra unnecessary columns. I added another step to delete columns in the newly created sheet prior to save however, that still did not address the issue.

To reiterate, I am having a user complete data on one sheet, I then after they click a button, split the sheet into two new sheets, I then save each new sheet as its own CSV workbook.  These are then used externally.  The newly created CSV files has excessive comma delimited columns that with my delete column sub, are still present.

thanks! Chris

Here is my code:

```
Sub Prepare()
    ReplaceWithValues
    SplitSheet
    ConvertDateFormat
    ExportToCSV
    DeleteSplitSheets
    DisplaySuccess
End Sub

Sub ReplaceWithValues()
' Removes all formulas from Data sheet and pastes only values
    Sheets("Data").Select

    Range("A3").Select
    Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub

Sub SplitSheet()
' Check to see if Contact sheet exists, if not create it
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    If Worksheets(i).Name = "Contacts" Then
        exists = True
    End If
    Next i

    If Not exists Then
        Worksheets.Add.Name = "Contacts"
    End If
' Splits out Contact data into new sheet for contact export
    Sheets("Data").Columns("A:V").Copy Sheets("Contacts").Range("A1")



' Check to see if Interactions sheet exists, if not create it
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    If Worksheets(i).Name = "Interactions" Then
        exists = True
    End If
    Next i

    If Not exists Then
        Worksheets.Add.Name = "Interactions"
    End If

' First copy over ID origin and ID to Interactions Sheet
    Sheets("Data").Columns("A:B").Copy Sheets("Interactions").Range("A1")
' Splits out Interaction Data into new Sheet for Interaction export
    Sheets("Data").Columns("W:AJ").Copy Sheets("Interactions").Range("C1")


End Sub

Sub ConvertDateFormat()
    Sheets("Interactions").Range("E3", "E50000").NumberFormat = "yyyymmddhhmmss"
End Sub

Sub ExportToCSV()
Dim dt As String

' Save Contacts File
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    If Worksheets(i).Name = "Contacts" Then
        exists = True
    End If
    Next i

    If exists Then

       DeleteEmptyColumns "Contacts"


        'Sheets("Contacts").Select
        'dt = Format(CStr(Now))
        dt = Format(Now(), "yyyymmddhhmmss")

        'filepart1 = "Bulk_Contacts_"

        fileSaveAsName = "Bulk_Contacts_" + dt

        'fileSaveAsName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileSaveAsName)
        fileSaveAsName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=fileSaveAsName, FileFilter:="csv Files (*.csv), *.csv")
        If fileSaveAsName = False Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'fileSaveAsName = fileSaveAsName + ".csv"

       ' ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fileSaveAsName, FileFormat:=xlUnicodeText, CreateBackup:=False
      ' ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.s Filename:=fileSaveAsName, FileFormat:=xlUnicodeText, CreateBackup:=False

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contacts").Copy

        On Error GoTo unSuccessful
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fileSaveAsName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True



    End If


' Save Interactions File
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        If Worksheets(i).Name = "Interactions" Then
            exists = True
        End If
        Next i

        If exists Then
            Sheets("Interactions").Select

            fileSaveAsName = "Bulk_Interactions_" & dt
            fileSaveAsName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=fileSaveAsName, FileFilter:="csv Files (*.csv), *.csv")
            If fileSaveAsName = False Then
                Exit Sub
            End If

            'fileSaveAsName = fileSaveAsName + ".csv"
           ' ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fileSaveAsName, FileFormat:=xlUnicodeText, CreateBackup:=False

            Application.DisplayAlerts = False

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Interactions").Copy

            On Error GoTo unSuccessful
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fileSaveAsName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True
            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If

        'MsgBox "Files Successfully Prepared and Exported!"
        Exit Sub


unSuccessful:
            MsgBox Err.Description
            Exit Sub

End Sub

Sub DeleteSplitSheets()
' Check if Interactions sheet exists and delete if present.
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
            If Worksheets(i).Name = "Interactions" Then
                exists = True
            End If
            Next i

            If exists Then
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                Sheets("Interactions").Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If

' Check if Contacts sheet exists and delete if present.
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
            If Worksheets(i).Name = "Contacts" Then
                exists = True
            End If
            Next i

            If exists Then
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                Sheets("Contacts").Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If
End Sub

Sub DisplaySuccess()
    MsgBox "Files Successfully Prepared and Exported!"
End Sub


Sub DeleteEmptyColumns(SheetName As String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName)
    lastCol = ws.Cells(2, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lastCol = lastCol + 1
   ' myCol = GetColumnLetter(lastCol)
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, lastCol).Address(True, False), "$")
    myCol = vArr(0)

    ws.Columns(myCol & ":XFD").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried saving each as .xlsx to verify that the extra commas appear?

Comment: I just tried this now and the result is the same, extra delimited columns.

Comment: If you can show an image of the original input, it may be useful.  In just looking at the code, I'm not seeing anything glaring.

Comment: Just to be sure, there are no commas floating around your source data?

Comment: In the spirit of @KarlKristjansson comment - have you reproduced this on a new file you've manually created with a known # of columns/rows?

Comment: hi all, Thanks for the replies.  I entered the test data and rechecked to ensure no commas, Same result.  Also, I manually copied and pasted the data into a new book and saved as CSV and that does not have the extra comma delimited columns.

Comment: Do you have a known number of commas showing up?  E.g., is it equivalent to the number of columns in the line: Sheets("Data").Columns("A:V").Copy Sheets("Contacts").Range("A1")
  (A=1, V=22, 21 comma separated values).

Comment: @Cyril The number of extra commas is 750k! It is insanity!

Comment: Since you are using Currentregion, you probably have a space in every cell to 750k. Try this in your macro, get rid Currentregion and then select the actual range of cells that you want to copy, paste into a new worksheet, save as a .cvs file, then open with Notepad, you will not get the commas.

Comment: Remove Sub SplitSheet(), and 

Add onto each copy paste... ".PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False"

Comment: @GMalc59 I am only using currentregion to copy paste values only into main sheet to remove formulas.  When I split the sheets, I am doing it by columns. See:Sheets("Data").Columns("A:V").Copy Sheets("Contacts").Range("A1") and ' First copy over ID origin and ID to Interactions Sheet
    Sheets("Data").Columns("A:B").Copy Sheets("Interactions").Range("A1")
' Splits out Interaction Data into new Sheet for Interaction export
    Sheets("Data").Columns("W:AJ").Copy Sheets("Interactions").Range("C1")

Answer (score 0):

All, Thanks for your replies.  I found the issue.  I was performing a column format and rather than taking only rows that were populated, I was formatting all rows.  This was causing the excess blank delimited columns.